# Unit-testing VueJS component doesn't seem to register click() invocation

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a fairly simple VueJS component called "Reveal"; it hides a message until somebody clicks on it, like so:

```
<template>
<div>
    <div v-show="!isShowing">
        <span v-on:click="show">ANSWER (Click to reveal)</span>
    </div>
    <div v-show="isShowing">
        <span v-on:click="hide">{{ message }} (Click to hide)</span>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['message'],
    data() {
        return {
            isShowing: false
        };
    },
    methods: {
        show: function() {
            this.isShowing = true;
        },
        hide: function() {
            this.isShowing = false;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Now I'm trying to test it with the following Reveal.spec.js, using Mocha+Chai, like so:

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Reveal from '@/components/Reveal.vue'

describe('Reveal.vue', () => {
  it('doesn\'t reveal the message when instantiated', () => {
    const msg = 'secret message'
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Reveal, {
      propsData: { 
        message: msg
      }
    })

    const spans = wrapper.findAll('span')
    expect(spans.length).to.equal(2);

    expect(spans.at(0).text()).to.include("ANSWER");
    expect(spans.at(0).isVisible()).to.be.true;

    expect(spans.at(1).text()).to.include(msg);
    expect(spans.at(1).isVisible()).to.be.false;
  })

  it('reveals the message when clicked', () => {
    const msg = 'secret message'
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Reveal, {
      propsData: {
        message: msg 
      }
    })
    wrapper.trigger('click')

    const spans = wrapper.findAll('span')
    expect(spans.length).to.equal(2);

    expect(spans.at(0).text()).to.include("ANSWER");
    expect(spans.at(0).isVisible()).to.be.false;

    expect(spans.at(1).text()).to.include(msg);
    expect(spans.at(1).isVisible()).to.be.true;
  })
})
```

My problem is that the call to wrapper.trigger() doesn't seem to actually trigger the click--or, perhaps more accurately, the "v-show" doesn't seem to be accurately reflected in the resulting DOM nodes, since the first span appears to remain visible even though after the click the isShowing boolean should be flipping its value.

I'm absolutely certain I'm misunderstanding what's going on here, because something this simple should be blindingly straightforward. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Just find the native html element and run `click()` on it, works every time.

Comment: For example, something along the lines of `wrapper.find('button').click()` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trigger` dispatches an Event on the root element of the wrapper. Your event listener is on a `span` element, so you need to use `find` to access a Wrapper containing the `span` element, before calling `trigger`:

```js
const spans = wrapper.findAll('span')

spans.at(1).trigger('click')
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! Wish the Vue docs were more clear about this. This is well-covered in your book, I take it? :-)

Comment: It is indeed ; )